# Print Data in Dictionary by using groovy

Tags: groovy

I have dictionary

```
Output = [a:2, c:13, b:5, z:'Test']
```

I use for loop as follows

```
   for(i in Output){
       println(Output[i.key]);
   }
```

it is result.

```
2
13
5
Test
```

but I expect result (reverse).

```
Test    
5
13
2
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Don't use uppercase variables.  Sooner or later the groovy parser will confuse that with a class name and will choke on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a "dictionary" (this is not Python), but a `Map`.

The order of its entries is not defined it is just a mapping key to value without any ordering. The order you get is (pseudo-)random and can not be depended upon.

Btw. the more Groovy way for producing the output would be to not use a for-loop, but e. g.

```
[a:2, c:13, b:5, z:'Test'].values().each { println it }
```

If you want to have an order, you need a list instead of a map, e. g. like a list of maps as in

```
[[a:2], [c:13], [b:5], [z:'Test']].reverse().collectMany { it.values() }.each { println it }
```

or a list of lists as in

```
[['a', 2], ['c', 13], ['b', 5], ['z', 'Test']].reverse().collect { it[1] }.each { println it }
```

or maybe this list of maps which probably would be the cleanest of these solutions

```
[[key:'a', value:2], [key:'c', value:13], [key:'b', value:5], [key:'z', value:'Test']].reverse().collect { it.value }.each { println it }
```

Comment: In OPs example it's actually ordered, as the groovy map literal gives you `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @cfrick sure, but that is an implementation detail, it is not guaranteed, is it?

Comment: Its guaranteed to have insertion order (well by the docs). Picking the right `Map` implementation is the responsibility of the developer to get such properties.  So sure, for a `Map` all bets are off and you are safer to assume no order, sorting, whatever.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` yes, but using a `Map` literal in Groovy does not guarantee this, does it?

Comment: The docs mention that a `LinkedHashMap` is generated, but I personally would not depend on this.